# Eclipse New Android Application 5 minutes ago had Empty Activity option

Tags: android, eclipse

Empty Activity option has disappeared from this options:

As you can see there are following options:

- Blank Activity
- Fullscreen Activity
- Master/Detail Flow

But no `Empty Activity`.

[image]

This screen was appearing from `File->New->Android Application Project->Next->Next->Next`

How can I find it? Where it disappeared?

Comment: What's the difference between *blank* and *empty* then?

Comment: Blank has no activity in it, Empty have some very basic, which I need usually.

Comment: Ok don't forget to specify your eclipse and android sdk versions

Comment: All latest, downloaded 2 hours ago.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the versions please, so 'we' can try to reproduce this and look for a cause/solution

Comment: Eclipse Release 4.3.0 (Last revised May 29th, 2013) from release notes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between "empty" and "blank". Blank creates an activity with a placeholder fragment, empty doesn't have the fragment.

I have had a similar problem today using the 20140321 ADT bundle. The x64 Eclipse on my laptop offers six templates when using the New Activity wizard, and four with the New Application. Both include "empty" and "blank".

I installed the x32 version of the same bundle on some student computers today, and Empty is missing in both wizards. This was a real pain, because we don't cover fragments until day 2, and it breaks all the classroom lab exercises ... :-(

BTW, I understand that "blank" used to be the only option, and did not generate a fragment. Something does seem to have changed here.

Thanks!

Steve.

Comment: It should be configured remotely? There is no other option. We haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 1):

As of ADT Version 23.0.0.1245622 (*)

- **Blank Activity** creates an Android Project without any Activity
  (src-Folder stays empty)
- **Empty Activity** creates an Android Project
  with one Activity (extended from Activity)

*= could be in an earlier version